# How to set component Maximum age field in Nexus repository 3.5 using API's

Tags: nexus

I am using the simple create script to add the script to the repo manager successfully : https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/nexus-3.x/scripting/simple-shell-example/create.sh

and passing a JSON file like this

```
{ 
"name": "apachesnapshots",

"type": "groovy", 

"content": "repository.createMavenProxy('apachesnapshots-io', 
 'http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/', 'default' ,org.sonatype.nexus.repository.proxy.ContentMaxAge.-1)"

}
```

For Release repositories, it says that the Maximum component age should be -1. I am getting 1440 by default. I have figured out the parameter that i need to pass in repository.createMavenProxy() should be ContentMaxAge. But not able to figure out if it should be added at a particular position and how to set its value to -1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Repository Manager within the API to get attributes and then change them accordingly.

To see the configuration, use a script like:

```
return repository.getRepositoryManager().get('my-proxy-repo').getConfiguration()
```

To change them, use something like:

```
repository.getRepositoryManager().get('my-proxy-repo').getConfiguration().getAttributes().'proxy'.'contentMaxAge' = -1
```

Hope it helps,
Steve